# Matplotlib interference figure strange pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, animation, physics

I am trying to make an [interference figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_interference) animation like this one:

[image]

The difference is that the above image shows the interference figure over time, so the constructive and destructive interference points remain fixed. On the contrary, I am trying to make an animation where I change the frequency of the two sources, keeping them fixed in the space.
Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

source = 0.5
sources = [-source, source]
axlim = max(sources)*2 + 1
N = 1000

x = np.linspace(-axlim, axlim, N)
y = np.linspace(-axlim, axlim, N)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

fig = plt.figure()

def update(f):
    plt.gca().cla()
    C1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*f*((X - sources[0])**2 + Y**2))
    C2 = np.sin(2*np.pi*f*((X - sources[1])**2 + Y**2))
    Z = C1 + C2

    plt.contour(X, Y, Z)

    plt.plot(sources, [0, 0], 'ro')
    plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
    plt.axis('off')

ani = FuncAnimation(fig = fig, func = update, frames = 11, interval = 100)

plt.show()
```

[image]

The issue is that strange patterns appear like in the last frames:

[image]

those patterns are not physical (they are not consistent with physics' laws), so there must be an error in my code. I cannot find out where, but I think the issue is in the matplotlib `contour` function: I suspect it introduce a sort of aliasing...

Comment: Those are moire patterns.   Suggest you use interpolation=hanning to minimize.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_antialiasing.html

Comment: Oops sorry I see you are using contour.   It’s still the same problem: you don’t have enough dpi to resolve the highest frequencies in your matrix.  I’d figure out how many dots you need to represent your axes and then make your simulation less than half as big in each dimension so each pixel is oversampled.  Ie make N considerably smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in your definition of `C1` and `C2`: you apply the sinusoidal function to the sum of the squared x and y distances, without applying a squared root. You should use:

```
C1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*f*np.sqrt((X - sources[0])**2 + Y**2))
C2 = np.sin(2*np.pi*f*np.sqrt((X - sources[1])**2 + Y**2))
```

---

There is no issue with the `contour` plot method, however, I suggest you to replace it with `contourf` or, even better, `imshow`. The reason is that `contour` plot lines where your field has the same value, keeping the rest of the plot empty. On the contrary, `contourf` or `imshow` fill the empty space with the colormap you choose, so you can display your field in a better way and avoid ambiguous white spaces.
See this code for reference:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

source = 0.5
sources = [-source, source]
axlim = max(sources)*2 + 1
N = 1000

x = np.linspace(-axlim, axlim, N)
y = np.linspace(-axlim, axlim, N)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

norm = plt.Normalize(-2, 2)
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', ['black', 'white', 'black'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def update(f):
    ax.cla()
    C1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*f*np.sqrt((X - sources[0])**2 + Y**2))
    C2 = np.sin(2*np.pi*f*np.sqrt((X - sources[1])**2 + Y**2))
    Z = C1 + C2

    ax.imshow(Z,
              cmap = cmap,
              norm = norm)
    ax.plot(N/2*(1 + source/axlim), N/2, 'ro')
    ax.plot(N/2*(1 - source/axlim), N/2, 'ro')

    ax.set_title(f'f = {f} Hz')
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    ax.axis('off')

ani = FuncAnimation(fig = fig, func = update, frames = 11, interval = 100)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Since peaks and valleys of your field are both constructive interference points, while in the destructive points the field is null, I chose a black - white - black colormap, you cannot distinguish peaks from valleys but it is easier to distinguish constructive from destructive interference points.